# Why I'm Getting negative x value when I configure the tk()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def openpic(self):
    self.filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() 
    self.openpicture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.filename))
    self._canvas.itemconfig(self.object, image=self.openpicture)
    self.pictureValue = self._canvas.bbox(self.object)
    self._canvas.config(width = self.pictureValue[2], height= self.pictureValue[3])
    self.picturewidth = self.pictureValue[2] - self.pictureValue[0]
    self.pictureheight = self.pictureValue[3] - self.pictureValue[1]
    posx = str(int(self._top.winfo_screenwidth()/2) - int((self.picturewidth + 100)/2))
    posy = str(int(self._top.winfo_screenheight()/2) - int((self.pictureheight/2)))
    framex = str(str(self.picturewidth + 100) + "x" + str(self.pictureheight) + "+" + posx + "+" + posy)
    print(framex)
    self._picture_Frame.configure(str(framex))
```

if I print framex the result will be 712x816+412+24 but in runtime the 712 become -712, please help me!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Used `abs`.

```
framex = str(str(abs(self.picturewidth + 100)) + "x" + str(self.pictureheight) + "+" + posx + "+" + posy)
```